# Dual Booting windows after installing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have system with ubuntu  20.04.Previously i didn't dual booted alongside windows thinking i may not need windows,but now i want to install windows dualbooted alongside ubuntu.Is it possible to install windows without removing ubuntu.I have heard ubuntus grub manager is destroyed by windows and only windows stays after installing,is it true?HOw can i install please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and don't fear nothing is going to happen to your ubuntu. I myself dual-booted windows10 with ubuntu last month.

First, there are plenty of video on youtube.

```
Things to notice:
```

1. `use GParted or something-else create some space below your boot/EFI and install windows there.`

Windows create `MSP partition`(why I don't know) of about 16-100MB, which if you touched then your windows will not boot. (it happened with me)
[image]

when you install `windows MSP will be above your C drive` (like in my case it's sda2 - MSP and sda3 - C). Now I will suggest you to install windows in an empty partition above your ubuntu partition otherwise that MSP will give you the following troubles which can be sorted using paid software

-- you can't move or resize MSP which implies that if it is in between ubuntu and windows partition then you can't resize them.

(eg. ubuntu --100gb/MSP-16mb/windows--100gb, now if you want to shrink ubuntu and extend windows you can't do that)

2. `If you have to make bootable USB of windows I will suggest` woeUSB terminal `because I think its GUI have some bugs so go with the terminal.`

if any question feel free to ask in comments.